# How to get rows of a tsv file with common values in one of the columns using pandas?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, pandas

I have a tsv (tab separated) file with data like this:

```
1 102 apple
2 102 orange
3 103 grapes
4 103 banana
5 103 carrot
```

I want to get the rows of the file which have common values in the second field. And, then I want to perform operations on individual elements of each group. So I added field names at the top like this:

```
A B   C
1 102 apple
2 102 orange
3 103 grapes
4 103 banana
5 103 carrot
```

I read the data in pandas as:

`data = pd.read_csv('mydata.tsv', error_bad_lines=False)`

and tried using `groupby`:

`g1 = data.groupby('B')`

But I get an error which says:

```
# duplicate columns & possible reduce dimensionality
KeyError: 'B'
```

data.info() gives me this:

`<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 2481 entries, 0 to 2480
Data columns (total 1 columns):
A   B   C    2481 non-null object
dtypes: object(1)
memory usage: 19.5+ KB`

I'm using python 2.7.

Comment: You have one column... look answer below, and try again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would be helpful to see the output of `df.info()` after `pd.read_csv()`. In any case, you should probably do

```
pd.read_csv(file, sep='\t', header=None)
```

and then set the columns using

```
df.columns = ['A', 'B', 'C']
```

or do the same in a single step:

```
pd.read_csv(file, sep='\t', header=None, names=['A', 'B', 'C'])
```

Then `.groupby('B')` should work fine, assuming you can read the file without errors.

Comment: pd.read_csv(file, sep='\t', header=None, names=['A', 'B', 'C'] ),. No?

Comment: That would also work. The point is that manually adding columns may throw  off the tab separation.